# A change of variables where mapping isn't straightforward

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am taking multivariable calculus and we are on change of variables; a particular problem was posed that doesn't seem solvable to me.

The region is bounded by $xy = 1, xy = 4$; that's easy; set $u = xy$.

But the region is also bounded by $y = \frac x2, y = x^2$.  Thus $v$ isn't as simple as $\frac yx$, as many examples do show us (giving us bounds such as $y = x$ and $y = 2x$).

How can I solve for $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?  After all, the power of one of the bounds differs from its supposed counterpart bound ($y =\frac x2$ is linear while $y = x^2$ is polynomial)?

The farthest I can get is determining that $\frac yx =\frac 12$ and $\frac yx = 2x$; but if $v$ is to have constant boundaries that don't involve itself, this doesn't work.  Is this problem doable, or is it some sort of typo?

[Graph of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qF7b.png)

Related question, but not relevant: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150656/how-to-find-a-good-strategy-for-tackling-change-of-variables-in-multivariable-ca)

Comment: Try using Desmos to plot the region.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done this already, but this does not clarify to me how to approach the problem at hand.

Comment: Nobody says that we can always find a change of variables with all constant boundaries. The point is to simplify the original task to something more manageable -- as compared to the original task. In the original problem here the region is so complicated that integrating it directly in terms of $x$ and $y$ requires cutting it into three pieces. If we can find a substitution that simplifies the region of integration into one (double) integral, that would be great! And it's okay if the limits for $v$ aren't constant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I can accept that the limits for $v$ may not be constant.  But that isn't the main problem.  If the limits for $v$ must have some power of $u$ (hence not constant), it is nonetheless challenging to produce a suitable change of variables without using itself ($v$) in its own boundaries.  For the attempt I described, $v = y/x$, I would create a region in which the boundaries of $v$ are not of the same _power_ of x.  This is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on our discussion in the comments under your original post: this problem is a bit tricky because I'm pretty sure we can't make a change with both new variables varying within constant limits.

Next, as a disclaimer: I don't know how to explain any general approach to such problems; it's more of a trial-and-error to me, plus learning various tricks from examples.

Now, let's get to the actual question here. After deciding on the most natural choice for $u=xy$, so $1\le u\le4$, what can we define as our $v$? And the trick here is that we don't have to change both, i.e. we can keep one of the old variables. So let's keep $y$ as the second variable; or rather, we should say that we define $v=y$.

Before we proceed, note that from the graph of the original domain we know that $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$, and therefore also $u\ge0$. So this is how this substitution is going to work: we're going to multiply the first equation by $y$ and the second equation by $y^2$ in order to create copies of $u$ (so to speak) on the right-hand sides.
$$\begin{aligned}
&y=\frac{1}{2}x \implies y^2=\frac{1}{2}xy \implies y^2=\frac{1}{2}u \implies y=\sqrt{u/2} \implies v=\sqrt{u/2}; \\
&y=x^2 \implies y^3=x^2y^2 \implies y^3=u^2 \implies y=u^{2/3} \implies y=u^{2/3} \implies v=u^{2/3}.
\end{aligned}$$
For $1\le u\le4$, the second graph lies above the first, giving us boundaries of integration for $v$.

[image]